# Need help to understand fun with anagram code

Tags: python, string, data-structures, anagram

The question is this:
Given an array of strings, remove each string that is an anagram of an earlier string, then return the remaining array in sorted order.

Example
str = ['code', 'doce', 'ecod', 'framer', 'frame']

code and doce are anagrams. Remove doce from the array and keep the first occurrence code in the array.

code and ecod are anagrams. Remove ecod from the array and keep the first occurrence code in the array.

code and framer are not anagrams. Keep both strings in the array.

framer and frame are not anagrams due to the extra r in framer. Keep both strings in the array.

Order the remaining strings in ascending order: ['code','frame','framer'].

The solution code is:

```
def checkForAnagrams(word, arr):
    # Checking if the word has an anagram in the sliced array.
    for x in arr:
        if (sorted(word) == sorted(x)):
            return True
    return False
            
def funWithAnagrams(text):
    limit = len(text)
    text.reverse()
    # Creating a copy of the list which will be modified,
    # and will not affect the array slicing during the loop.
    final_text = list(text)

    # Looping through the list in reverse since we're eliminating
    # the second anagram we find from the original list order.
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, limit):
        if text[i+1:] and checkForAnagrams(text[i], text[i+1:]):
            final_text.pop(i - count)
            count += 1

    return sorted(final_text)
```

I want to understand in the function funwithanagrams, how is the text[i+1:] useful?

```
if checkForAnagrams(text[i], text[i+1:]):
```

would have achieved the same output.

PS-This is not my code. I found it online and really want to know how the text[i+1:] will impact the output if removed?

Comment: `text[i+1:]` is all the remaining elements of the list.

Comment: So it's just checking whether there are any anagrams for `text[i]` in the rest of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The `if text[i+1:]` checks whether the sliced list is empty or not. If it wasn't there, in the final iteration of the for loop, an error would've occurred when iterating through `text[i+1:]` as it would be empty. The `if text[i+1:]` equates to False in the last iteration due to which `checkForAnagrams(text[i], text[i+1:])` never executes and no error occurs.

A better way to write this code would be to remove the `if text[i+1:]` and instead replace `range(0, limit)` with `range(0, limit-1)` so that `text[i+1:]` is never empty (will have one element in the last iteration of the for loop). This method would reduce the number of checks required and make the code more efficient (doesn't make a noticeable difference for a code this small).